# if statement and call function for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I know how to apply an `IF` condition in `Pandas` DataFrame. [link](https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/)

However, my question is how to do the following:

```
if (df[df['col1'] == 0]):
   sys.path.append("/desktop/folder/")
   import self_module as sm
   df = sm.call_function(df)
```

What I really want to do is when value in `col1` equals to 0 then call function `call_function()`.

```
def call_function(ds):
   ds['new_age'] = (ds['age']* 0.012345678901).round(12)
   return ds
```

I provide a simple example above for `call_function()`.

Comment: Just curious, why are you reassign `df = sm.call_function(df)`? Do you mean `df = sm.call_function(df[df['col1']== 0])`, that is, to transform only part of the data?

Comment: I want to do the whole data for `call_function()` if `df['col1']== 0`, for those not equal to 0, leave `pd.NaT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function interacts with multiple columns and returns a whole data frame, run conditional logic inside the method:

```
def call_function(ds):
   ds['new_age'] = np.nan
   ds.loc[ds['col'] == 0, 'new_age'] = ds['age'].mul(0.012345678901).round(12)

   return ds

df = call_function(df)
```

If you are unable to modify the function, run method on splits of data frame and `concat` or `append` together. Any new columns in other split will be have values filled with NAs.

```
def call_function(ds):
   ds['new_age'] = (ds['age']* 0.012345678901).round(12)
   return ds

df = pd.concat([call_function(df[df['col'] == 0].copy()),
                df[df['col'] != 0].copy()])
```

Comment: I got the error with second way: `TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"`

Comment: Whoops! `pd.concat` takes a list and not comma-separated objects. See edit.